# How to use custom fonts on a Next.js app under a sub-path of a domain?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js app deployed under a sub-path of a domain (e.g. `example.com/my-next-js-app`). For the bundle scripts and styles, I was able to resolve them using Next.js config:

```json
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
module.exports = {
  basePath: isProd ? '/my-next-js-app' : '',
};
```

For images, I'm able to create a function that will add a prefix to the image url if it's on `production` env.

```
export function getAssetUrl(path: string) {
  return process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? `${MAIN_URL}${path}` : path;
}
```

But for the fonts, I'm not quite sure what is the recommended way. Currently I have custom font faces in my `styles/globals.css` as below:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('/fonts/MyCustomFont-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('/fonts/MyCustomFont-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('/fonts/MyCustomFont-BoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-display: swap;
}
```

So when deployed, fonts will not be in the root public folder but it will be in `example.com/my-next-js-app/fonts/MyCustomFont-xxx.ttf`.

Comment: Where are your fonts currently located? You could maybe place them in public and then import them in your custom document.

Comment: Use `assetPrefix: isProd ? '/my-next-js-app/' : '/'` along with your `basePath` setting.

Comment: @brc-dd nope that didn't work, that seems to be only added for JavaScript and CSS assets generated by Next, but does not modify the urls inside a stylesheet. So inspecting the CSS generated after adding the prefix, it is still `url('/fonts/MyCustomFont-Regular.ttf')`

Comment: @user10532439 yeah, images and css urls needs to be changed. If you use `'../public/fonts/fontFile.ttf'` it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue by creating a component which contains the font face styles in an inline style appended to the `<head>` with the help of `Head` from `next/head`. This way, I can utilize the `getAssetUrl()` function based on the correct asset URL.

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import React from 'react';
import { getAssetUrl } from '../lib/assets';

export default function FontFaces() {
  return (
    <Head>
      <style
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
            @font-face {
              font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 400;
              src: url('${getAssetUrl('fonts/MyCustomFont-Regular.ttf')}') format('truetype');
              font-display: swap;
            }

            @font-face {
              font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 700;
              src: url('${getAssetUrl('fonts/MyCustomFont-Bold.ttf')}') format('truetype');
              font-display: swap;
            }

            @font-face {
              font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
              font-style: italic;
              font-weight: 700;
              src: url('${getAssetUrl('fonts/MyCustomFont-BoldItalic.ttf')}') format('truetype');
              font-display: swap;
            }
          `,
        }}
      />
    </Head>
  );
}
```